# not able to cancel observable from rxjs 5.0

Tags: rxjs

I have this function:

```
 uploadFiles(files: FileToUpload[]) {
    return Observable.create(async (observable) => {
      const aborters: Aborter[] = [];

      for (const fileToUpload of files) {
        let uploadResponse: UploadResponse;

        const aborter = Aborter.none;

        aborters.push(aborter);

        try {
          uploadResponse = await this.upload(file)
        } catch (err) {
        }
      }

      return () => {
        console.log('coooo');

        this.files$.next([]);

        for (const aborter of aborters) {
          if (!aborter.aborted) {
            aborter.abort();
          }
        }
      };
    });
  }
```

I want this observable to be cancellable when the user navigates awwy from the apge if there is a download happening so I am returning a function that is called when unsubscribe calls.

I then subscribe like this:

```
this.uploadSubscription = this.uploadService.uploadFiles(this.control.value).subscribe(
      () => console.log('progress'),
      (e) => {
        console.log(`errored with ${e}`);
        this.uploadSubscription.unsubscribe();
      },
      () => {
        console.log('completed');
        this.uploadSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    );
```

And I have an `ngOnDestroy` like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.uploadSubscription) {
      this.uploadSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

But even though the unsubscribe method is called, the callback returned from `Observable.create` is not called.

Comment: I suppose you can use `takeUntil`.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html

Comment: I need the callback to be called and it is not getting called

Comment: tried takeUntil also with a `destry$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that from the `Observable.create` callback you're in fact returning a Promise and not a teardown method.

You marked the callback with `async` keyword so it returns a Promise so when you later call `return () => {}` you're actually returning `Promise<() => void>` so it's never invoked. Not even when you call `unsubscribe`.

You'd have to restructure the chain in order to make it unsubscribable depending on what you want to do but it seems like you might not even need to use `await` because you never push any notifications to the `observer`.

Comment: absolutely, what a twit.  of course async returns a promise.  Thank you